# Uber api deep link in android with javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, uber-api

I am working on an ionic app and am trying to create a deep link to the uber app from mine and make the link work from android. I have gone through the Uber API documentation and have tried to call the universal link in multiple ways but its not working on the device. When i try to click on the button from ionic serve in the browser on my laptop it takes me to the uber mobile webpage where it asks me to open uber or download it but when i try this on the android device nothing happens :(

I am providing the code below. If someone can point out if i am missing something please let me know. Your help's very much appreciated.

The HTML

```
<a href="#" ng-click="callUber()" class="no-bg-btn">
  Call Uber          
</a>
```

The Angular function

```
 $scope.callUber = function(){

 var url = 'https://m.uber.com/ul/?action=setPickup';
 $http.get(url)
    .then( function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      $window.location.href = url;
    }, function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
 };
```

I have also tried putting the Uber universal link in the https://m.uber.com/ul/?action=setPickup' tag but that doesnt work either.

Comment: What browser do you use to open the deeplink? Check out the [support for deeplinks documentation for more details](https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/deep-linking-universal-links#support-for-universal-links)

Comment: Hi agraebe I am using the default browser "internet" that came with the S5 I have installed firefox on it as well...when i click on the button im guessing its using the default "internet" browser thats on marshmellow.

Comment: The link looks good and it works on my phone. I'm not an angularjs expert, but the $http.get call loads the content of the page. Why do you need to do that? Could you try the same deeplink and put it into the link itself, like so: <a href="https://m.uber.com/ul/?action=setPickup" class="no-bg-btn">Call Uber</a>